# What is the difference between these evaluators in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was browsing and I came across several different notations. I wanted to know the fundamental difference.

Let's declare

```
var foo = "bar";
```

Now, I already knew about of the ternary/Elvis operator:

```
var x = (foo == "bar")? "yes" : "no";
>> "yes"
```

Or, more simply,

```
var x = (foo == "bar");
>> true
```

However, what about these functions?

```
var a = ["no", "yes"][+(foo == "bar")];
>> "yes"
```

My take: `[+(foo == "bar")]` evaluates to `[+(true)]` and, with type coercion, to `[+1]`. Then, it accesses the second element of the array.

```
var b = ["no", "yes"][foo == "bar" & 1];
>> "yes"
```

My take: `[foo == "bar" & 1]` evaluates to `[true & 1]`. Then, (in binary) to `[01 & 00000001]`, which returns `1` as the array index accessor.

```
var c = ["no", "yes"][foo == "bar" && 1];
>> "yes"
```

My take: Similar to above, except type coercion caused `[true && 1]` to evaluate to `[1]`.

Which notation is the fastest? Which notation is the most readable/reliable? Is there anything I missed?

Comment: You don't have any return statements. Which one is fastest? Who knows. Test it in every browser/server and find out.

Comment: @cookiemonster Oh, I forgot to change the title after I made them not `return` statements. What is the best way to time them, though? I've never done something like that.

Comment: I can't imagine any developer using any of the versions below the conditional operator.

Comment: or var x = foo == "bar"

Comment: @attila I put that as the second example, just with parentheses.

Comment: I'm a big fan of efficiency over code readability, but even I have my limits. Ternary operator is the best I'll go for in this scenario, as the others are too expansive. It's all a matter of preference and style, really.

Comment: Could you use var time1 = new Date().getTime(); before the evaluator and var time2 = newDate().getTime(); after the evaluator, then alert time2 - time1. Also, have you tried www.jsperf.com ?

Comment: http://jsperf.com is your new friend

Comment: Your last one will fail when the `foo=="bar"` is `false`.

Comment: `(foo == "bar")?` throws an error

Comment: @Oriol Yeah, it's supposed to be `(foo == "bar")`—I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
(foo === "bar")? "yes" : "no";
```

will always be faster than the array versions and in my opinion, will always be easier to read. Though, I suspect, you know that because you felt you needed to explain the other examples but not the ternary operator.

The reason the others are slower is that they require an array allocation and then an array lookup. The engine can be smart here by realizing it can make the array constant and only allocate it once by I wouldn't expect any runtime to do this because there are more performant, easier to understand, idioms to do the same thing.

In general, if you have a solution that avoids an allocation, use it. Allocations are an enemy to performance.

As for what you have missed, there are an infinite list of possible solutions to this but none of them will be faster than the ternary operator.

Note, also, the switch to using the `===` operator instead of `==` which avoids type coercion.

Comment: I ran it on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/evaluator-times) and it actually about 10% faster than the 3rd example. The last two were 2% slower.

Comment: @Luxelin: Don't put `console.log()` in a performance test. Put in only the minimal code examples. The code is going to be run thousands of times, so all that logging isn't going to help anything.

Comment: @cookiemonster I didn't even think of that! [It](http://jsperf.com/evaluator-times) now shows drastic differences.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about readability I'd say that the ones that rely on type coercion and binary ops are not well readable. Not conventional ways taught in Javascript tutorials and familiar to many but more like accidents that happen to work. I have to say the last one looks kind of nice but I still would not use any but the ternary operator.

For the ternary operator there are clear documents with examples such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator . When searching for alternatives I did not find any documents out there promoting the use of the alternatives you gave.